# How to select sum of column values using from and to time values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure.

```
id    time     value
1     00:01      5
2     00:02      4
3     00:03      4
4     00:04      9
5     00:05      7
..    ....      ...
..    ....      ...
..    ....      ...
240   03:59      4
241   04:00      5
242   04:01      4
243   04:02      4
244   04:03      9
245   04:04      7
..    ....      ...
..    ....      ...
..    ....      ...
xxx   08:00      4
```

How can i sum the values field from with every 4 hours difference(individual for every 4 hours). 
from 00:01 to 04:00 and 04:01 to 08:00 and so on

The usual code for sum in sql i usually use is :

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM table WHERE (condition)";
$rowNum = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rowNum);

echo  $count["total"];
```

So, my question is in the "condition" field how should i tell it to get just 4 hours of columns only..?

Any Help is greatly appreciated. And thank you for going through the question.

Comment: Rough draft: calculate difference to first entry in hours, divide by 4, group by that number, (`GROUP BY (time - (SELECT  time FROM table ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1))/(60*60*4) `) - mind that this pseudo code and you might or might not be able to subtract times like that depending on the data type you use to store them. Then just use an aggregate such as sum(value) to add them up.
You do not need any `where` for this at all.

Comment: @YourCommonSense This will do a sum for every hour, not for 4 hour steps

Comment: NavKiran, My solution above assumes you want 4 hour steps starting witrh the first entry. If that is not a requirement but any 4 hour step will do, you can use the easier approach @YourCommonSense suggested but add a division by 4 and rounding at the end.

Comment: @JohannesH. oh yes sure. SELECT SUM(value) AS total FROM table GROUP BY floor(HOUR(time)/4)*4